# Bluemix: service bound to container does not appear in VCAP_SERVICES

Tags: ssh, docker, containers, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use IBM Containers for Bluemix to deploy a container and bind it to a Bluemix service.

I start with an existing Bluemix app, which is bound to the MongoDB service I want. I verify that its `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable is correctly populated:

```
$ cf env mamacdon-app
Getting env variables for app mamacdon-app in org mamacdon@ca.ibm.com / space dev as mamacdon@ca.ibm.com...
OK

System-Provided:
{
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
        "mongodb-2.4": [
            {
                "credentials": { /*private data hidden*/ },
                "label": "mongodb-2.4",
                "name": "mongodb-1a",
                "plan": "100",
                "tags": [ "nosql", "document", "mongodb" ]
            }
        ]
    }
 ...
```

Then I run my image in Bluemix using the `ice` command, with the `--bind mamacdon-app` argument to bind it to my CF app:

```
$ ice run --name sshparty \
  --bind mamacdon-app \
  --ssh "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" \  # For SSH access
  --publish 22 \                      # For SSH access
  registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty:latest
```

As the name suggests, the image is a trivial example based on the IBM Websphere Liberty docker image -- just enough to let me SSH in and poke around.

At this point, the Containers dashboard tells me that the service has been bound to my container:

[image: Dashboard showing bound service]

But when I finally ssh into the container, the environment does not contain the `VCAP_SERVICES` variable:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@129.41.232.212
root@instance-000123e2:~# env
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=[private data hidden]
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=[omitted]
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=[private data hidden]
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
root@instance-000123e2:~#
```

I expected the `VCAP_SERVICES` variable to be injected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the way the ssh daemon is getting launched where it does not have visibility to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.

However, you can confirm that the container's command will see the variable with following test:

```
ice run registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty --bind mamacdon-app --name vcap_services_party printenv; sleep 60
```

Then, confirm it in the printenv output with `ice logs vcap_services_party`

Comment: This worked. And yes, it seems that `sshd` doesn't inject the value of the `VCAP_SERVICES` variable into terminal sessions opened over SSH. The other processes in the container are able to see the VCAP_SERVICES variable just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the following a try:

```
ice run registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/lintest/tradelite --bind yourappname --name yournewcontainer name
```

Once the image comes up run the following.

```
# echo $VCAP_SERVICES
```

For more info check out the [Containers Docs.](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/cli.html#container_cli__run)